# Installing APC on 64bit Centos5, phpize error

Tags: linux, apc, centos5

This is probably a common question, but all answers on the internt have failed to help me. OK, so I want to install APC on my Centos5 server which is running php 5.3.5 and has all the following installed:

php-pear, php-devel, httpd-devel, pcre-devel and developer tools

but when i perfom either:

```
pecl install apc
```

or

```
pear install pecl/apc
```

I get a 'phpize' error. I also found an answer saying I could make /tmp executable but when I ran the code it said permission denied?

Anyone have a solution to this? I have no experience in linux or SSH by the way.

Or has anyone a really good tutorial on how to compile APC manually?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who has this issue, I found a very good tutorial on how to do this manually and it works first time!

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/install-apc-php-linux/

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the `php5-dev` package, which includes the `phpize` command. I don't know the command under CentOS, maybe

```
yum install php5-dev
```

Then

```
pecl install apc
```

should work without any error. I had the same error, and just managed to install it successfully under Debian.